# Autocompletion of filename doesn't work in a shell in a buffer, when the current working directory is moved

Tags: shell

In emacs, I press M-x shell to create a shell in a buffer.

In the shell, I can use autocomplete file names with respect to the current working directory.

If outside the shell e.g. in Nautilus, I move the current directory somewhere else, then back in the shell, the autocompletion of file names will not be working correctly, still with respect to the old pathname of the current working directory.

I tried to refresh the buffer of the shell by M-x revert-buffer, but it didn't work because the buffer didn't open a file but a shell.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`M-enter` will re-sync the directory. It is bound to `shell-resync-dirs`.

Basic functionality of the function is to call `command dirs` This can be altered by changing variable `shell-dirstack-query`. Because output is read directly from the buffer code can get confused, if it reads wrong line.

Sometimes Emacs says "Couldn’t cd: (error No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable)". One of the reason is that the resync command does not read the right path from the output. It does not expect command to be echoed by the shell process. In this case change `comint-process-echoes` to true.

If all else fails directory can be set manually using invoking cd-function (`M-x cd`).

Comment: Thanks, but `M-enter`  doesn't work.

Comment: Does the shell-resync-dirs?

Comment: When running `M-x  shell-resync-dirs`, it says `Couldn't cd`. it doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing `comint-process-echoes`to non-nil value. `M-x eval-expression` and `(setq comint-process-echoes t)`.

Comment: Still not works.

Comment: Then I suppose that my problems with shell resync are different than you are encountering. Have you debugged what goes wrong with the `shell-resync-dirs`. What does the `shell-dirstack-query`contain and what happens if you run that command manually.

Comment: can you point me to the places in the emacs manual where I can learn about debug what goes wrong with `shell-resync-dirs`?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html

Comment: Basically what you can do is to go to the `shell-resync-dirs` method. One way to navigate there is see methods documentation with `C-h f shell-resync-dirs`. The documentation contains link to the source code. You can edit that code by adding `(debug)` to the start. Then you need to eval the buffer so the change has effect. After that try doing the resync and step through the function. Reverse the steps to remove call to the debug command. One can also debug on entry as explained here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Debugging.html